# Key derivation in HD wallets using the extended private key vs hardened derivation

Tags: wallet, private-key, public-key, bip32-hd-wallets

I am reading the book [Mastering Bitcoin](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802) and confused about wallet key derivations in [Chapter 4. Keys, Addresses, Wallets](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch04.html#_wallets).

The book first mentions a [private child key derivation](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch04.html#CKDpriv) where the child private key is derived from three inputs: (parent public key previously derived from parent private key, parent chain code, index).

Next, the book discusses extended keys and mentions two types: extended private keys and extended public keys.

The extended public keys are used to derive children public keys from parents public keys to avoid exposing the private keys, hence more secure. This is the block diagram for the [extended public key](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch04.html#CKDpub).

On the other hand, the book mentions that the extended private key is used to derive a child's private key using the parent's private key and chain code.

However, although the extended public key does not expose the private key, it is still risky to use since it exposes the chain codes. If a private key is leaked, they can be used together to derive other children key.

Finally, the book suggest to use the [hardened key](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch04.html#CKDprime), which to me is exactly the same description as the extended private key.

My question first question is, is the extended private key the same thing as the hardened key derivation?

My second question is, which technique is actually used when deriving the private key for children, the first one I mention in my question or the second one using the extended private key which to me is the same exact thing as the hardened key derivation.

Answer (score 36):

There's a lot of confusion here, mostly bits and pieces of the whole scheme that is Hierarchical Deterministic derivation, and finally two questions that seem to indicate missing some point about it.
The answer to the first question is No.  The second question is more interesting :

Let's start from extended keys, specifically BIP32 keys.
Like private keys and public keys, extended keys can be either "private" or "public".  I put both in quotes becaus both types of extended keys do contain private information.
At least enough to track key use. This mechanism is used by hardware wallets and "watchonly" software wallets on a PC.

An extended key is just a base58 encoded serialization of a few pieces of data :

`[ magic ][ depth ][ parent fingerprint ][ key index ][ chain code ][ key ]`

Where `key` can be either a public key or a private key.  Private keys are prepended with a single `0x00` byte, so the length of this blob stays the same.
An extended key is usually derived by "traversing" some `path`, meaning you would start your derivation at some parent extended key, and consecutively derive child keys with specific indexes until you finally derive the final extended key in the `path`.
I'll stop using "extended" in this answer.  From now on I'll refer to an extended private key as `xprv` and to an extended public key as `xpub`, and just "keys" sometimes.  Non-extended are just "private key" or "public key".

An xprv or xpub's `magic` are 4 bytes to indicate the network it belongs to: testnet or mainnet (`t` or `x` respectively), and the type of key it is (`pub` and `prv` respectively).
The `depth` is a byte that indecates how deep an xpriv or xpout is in a path, starting from `00` as the depth of the `master` key, and incremented by one as the derivation of more child keys is done along the path.
Note that up until now, the only difference between `xprv` and `xpub` keys that I mentioned is the `prv` or `pub` part in the magic.
It also should be clear that an `xprv` and `xpub` can be in the same path, and in the same depth.  This means that for such pair of `xprv` and `xpub`, the `[ key ]` part of the will have a 32 byte private key (prepended with one `00` byte) in the `xprv`, and a 33 byte public key which is the public key which which you get from the private key in the `xprv`.

A parent's fingerprint are the first 4 bytes of the `hash160` of the *public key* of the parent.  This means that even if a parent `xprv` was used to derive a child `xprv`, it would have the same `parent fingerprint` as if a parent `xpub` was used to derive a child `xpub`.
A parent-child relationship between keys means that they are adjacent in a path.

A `path` is an n-tuple of indexes, usually in base 10, separated by `/`.  The range of an index can be between zero and and 4294967295 (or 2^32-1), where anything in `[0,2147483647]` follows *non-hardnened* derivation, and indexes in `[2147483648,4294967295]` follow *hardened* derivation.
You can see that each half of the range of indexes is used for a different method.  We can say that there are two ranges.  `[0,2147483647]` for non-hardened keys, and `[0h,2147483647h]` for hardened keys.  The `h` indicates that the index (we'll call it `i`) should be treated as `i + 2147483648`.
You're probably more likely to see the `h` notation as a caret `'` instead, so `1' == 1h`, but I don't think it's very pretty so I'll stick with `h` for now.

An example of what a path looks like is :

`m/0h/1/2h/2/1000000000`

The `m` means that the key at this index is a `master xprv` or `master xpub`.  A small `m` means that this extended key is a `master xprv`, and big `M` a `master xpub`.  Following the previous definitions, you can tell that `m` is the parent of the key at `0h`, and the key at `2h` is the child of the key before it at index `1`.
To make this easier to follow, we'll annote the different keys in the path with letters `{a..e}` if we mean that these are `xprv`s and `{A..B}` if `xpub`s.

```
m / 0h / 1 / 2h / 2 / 1000000000
m   a    b   c    d   e
```

A path is usually given with indexes in base10, but in the key itself they are encoded in hex (base16), so a `[ key index ]` is always 4 bytes with zeros prepended if needed.  The `depth` and `index` of a master key are both alwasy zero, so `00` and `00000000`, and they can get to a maximum of `FF` and `FFFFFFFF` respectively.
So `m` and `a` are parent and child, and so are `d` and `e`.  The `depth` of `b` is `02` and its index is `00000001`, and the `depth` of `c` is `03` while its index is `80000002` (80000000 + 2).
The last child key to be derived is `e`.  We can say that we followed a path starting at `m`, from it we derived the key `a` at index `0h`, then from `a` we derived the key `b` at index `1`.. and so on.  But what does it mean to derive a new key?

The remaining two elements in the extended key format, the parent's `[ chain code ]` and `[ key ]` are used together with what would be the child key's `index` to derive it. 
That means that to derive `c` from `b`, we'd feed some function with `b`'s `chain code` and `key`, and `c`'s `index`.
A specific example of our `b` and `c` would be :

```
b :

0488ADE4
02
5C1BD648
00000001
2A7857631386BA23DACAC34180DD1983734E444FDBF774041578E9B6ADB37C19
003C6CB8D0F6A264C91EA8B5030FADAA8E538B020F0A387421A12DE9319DC93368
```

---

```
c :

0488ADE4
03
BEF5A2F9
80000002
04466B9CC8E161E966409CA52986C584F07E9DC81F735DB683C3FF6EC7B1503F
00CBCE0D719ECF7431D88E6A89FA1483E02E35092AF60C042B1DF2FF59FA424DCA
```

The fields are ordered as in the structure above.  On both, the `magic` says `xprv`, the `depth` is incremented between the parent and child, the `fingerprint` at `c` is the `hash160` of the public key that you would get from the private key at `b`, and `b`'s `index` is in the first, non-hardened half of the range while `c`'s is the second, hardned half.  Finally the `chain code` and `key`s of each of the `xprv`s are encoded.

Deriving the `chain code` and `key` for `c` from `b` is done with a process called `CKDpriv`, which means deriving a child `xprv` from a parent `xprv`.  In this process we used the `chain code` and `key` from `b`, and the `index` from `c`.
The important point to make: We only encoded `c` *after* deriving its `chain code` and `key` from what would be its `index`.

Any `xprv` can be used with `CKDpriv` to derive a child `xprv` at any `index`.  The specific way `CKDpriv` will act on the input depends on the child's `index` being in the hardened range, or the non-hardned range.  Basically, a `CKDpriv` function runs an `HMAC-SHA512` on the parent's `chain code` and `key`, and the child's `index`.  This hmac function takes two values a `key*` (not to be confused with our occurences of `key`, will be refered to as `hkey`), and `text`.
The parent's `chain code` is used as the `hkey`, while the `text` is made up of the parent's `key` in the *private key* form if the the child's index is in the hardened range, `[0h,2147483647h]`, and in the *public key* form if the index is in the non-hardened range.  It is then concatenated with the child's `index`.

`c`'s index is in the hardened range, so `CKDpriv`'s hmac-sha512 runs with the inputs:

```
HMAC-SHA512( 2A7857631386BA23DACAC34180DD1983734E444FDBF774041578E9B6ADB37C19,
             003C6CB8D0F6A264C91EA8B5030FADAA8E538B020F0A387421A12DE9319DC9336880000002 )
```

Which returns a 64 byte hash :

```
8F6154A0A82D0F68B9E5B586EA66D951DAAA071BEBD390097CC516285C791A6204466B9CC8E161E966409CA52986C584F07E9DC81F735DB683C3FF6EC7B1503F
```

The 32 bytes on the right half of this hash, `04466B9C...C7B1503F` become the child's (`c` here) `chain code`, and the 32 bytes on the left are used to "tweak", meaning just "addition mod n" to the parent's key, in this example :

```
  8F6154A0A82D0F68B9E5B586EA66D951DAAA071BEBD390097CC516285C791A62
+
  3C6CB8D0F6A264C91EA8B5030FADAA8E538B020F0A387421A12DE9319DC93368
=
  CBCE0D719ECF7431D88E6A89FA1483E02E35092AF60C042B1DF2FF59FA424DCA   mod n
```

- I didn't write the `00` prepended bytes in the keys here because this is just adding numbers, but those zero bytes are very important for the hash function, so I purposely included them there.

Now that we've got `c`'s `chain code` and `key` (in private key form), we would want to actually encode `c` for it to be a usable `xprv`.
To get the `fingerprint` from `b`, we need to know the public key of the `key` from `b`.  Since it's in private key form, we'll have to do multiplication:

```
CBCE0D719ECF7431D88E6A89FA1483E02E35092AF60C042B1DF2FF59FA424DCA * G
= 03501E454BF00751F24B1B489AA925215D66AF2234E3891C3B21A52BEDB3CD711C
```

Take the `hash160` of this public key, and the returned hash is `BEF5A2F9A56A94AAB12459F72AD9CF8CF19C7BBE`.
The first four bytes are `b`'s fingerprint : `BEF5A2F9`.
Encoding the rest of `c` is easy.  Start with the magic `xprv` since we derived a child `xprv`, increment the depth of `b` by one, then the `fingerprint`.
Next `c`'s `index` is encoded.  We derived index `2h`, so this would be `80000002`, and then the new `chain code` and `key` that we got from `CKDpriv`.

This is basically what *hardened* derivation is.  The parent's private key and chain code are used to derive the child key at some hardened index.
What if we want to derive `d`?  It's at index `2`, so a non-hardened index.  This is the second case of `CKDpriv`.

The difference is in what is used for the `text` parameter of the `HMAC-SHA512` function.  Instead of using the parent's `key` in private key form, we use the public key form, so to derive `d` at index `2` from `c`, we first find the public key of `c` :

```
CBCE0D719ECF7431D88E6A89FA1483E02E35092AF60C042B1DF2FF59FA424DCA * G
= 0357BFE1E341D01C69FE5654309956CBEA516822FBA8A601743A012A7896EE8DC2
```

Then continue following the same steps as the above:

```
HMAC-SHA512( 04466B9CC8E161E966409CA52986C584F07E9DC81F735DB683C3FF6EC7B1503F,
             0357BFE1E341D01C69FE5654309956CBEA516822FBA8A601743A012A7896EE8DC200000002 )

                            tweak                                                            chain code
437984D45C4A2F5840C65B3DC6D7274E2859AD25D092DB032C49AA4D006A426B|CFB71883F01676F587D023CC53A35BC7F88F724B1F8C2892AC1275AC822A3EDD
```

* note that `00` is not prepended to the `text`, since this is a public key.

```
  437984D45C4A2F5840C65B3DC6D7274E2859AD25D092DB032C49AA4D006A426B
+
  CBCE0D719ECF7431D88E6A89FA1483E02E35092AF60C042B1DF2FF59FA424DCA
=
  0F479245FB19A38A1954C5C7C0EBAB2F9BDFD96A17563EF28A6A4B1A2A764EF4   mod n

hash160( 0357BFE1E341D01C69FE5654309956CBEA516822FBA8A601743A012A7896EE8DC2 )

finger
   print
EE7AB90C|DE56A8C0E2BB086AC49748B8DB9DCE72
```

The rest is easy, and we can encode :

```
d :

0488ADE4
04
EE7AB90C
00000002
CFB71883F01676F587D023CC53A35BC7F88F724B1F8C2892AC1275AC822A3EDD
000F479245FB19A38A1954C5C7C0EBAB2F9BDFD96A17563EF28A6A4B1A2A764EF4
```

The difference between these two methods of deriving child `xprv`s is subtle but important.  It enables `CKDpub`, which is a function to derive child `xpub`s from a *parent* `xpub`.  `CKDpub` works almost the same as `CKDpriv`'s non-hardened derivation, but it does the derivation using point addition,  so rather than adding up integers to make child private keys, we're adding up points to make child public keys.
Notice how in the non-hardened derivation we used the parent's public point for the `HMAC-SHA512`, we used the `tweak` as the added value to the parent private key to derive the child private key, specifically, we derived `d`'s private key.

To understand `CKDpub`, it helps to first know about yet another BIP32 function called `Neuter`.  It's purpose is to convert an `xprv` to an `xpub`.
Let's "run" `Neuter` on our `xprv` `d`.  We'll call the resulting `xpub` `D`.  `Neuter` does two things to an `xprv`:
1. Replace the `magic` from `0488ADE4` to `0488B21E` (replaces `xprv` with `xpub`)
2. Replaces the private key in the `key` field` with the public point of the same private key

for our `xprv` `d`, the public point is:

```
0F479245FB19A38A1954C5C7C0EBAB2F9BDFD96A17563EF28A6A4B1A2A764EF4 * G
= 02E8445082A72F29B75CA48748A914DF60622A609CACFCE8ED0E35804560741D29
```

(this is just normal process of private key -> public key)

so the result is:

```
D:

0488B21E
04
EE7AB90C
00000002
CFB71883F01676F587D023CC53A35BC7F88F724B1F8C2892AC1275AC822A3EDD
02E8445082A72F29B75CA48748A914DF60622A609CACFCE8ED0E35804560741D29
```

Now `d` is "neutered", `D` has the public key encoded, but see how the `chain code`, `depth`, `fingerprint` and `index` persisted.  The `xpub` `D` is at the same position in the path as the `xprv` `d`.  We will be using the `chain code` and `key` (public key) for `CKDpub`, same as `CKDpriv` with non-hardened derivation, but as for `CKDpriv`, we derived the child private key using:

```
tweak + (parent private key) = child private key
```

for `CKDpub` we will be using:

```
tweak*G + (parent public key) = child public key
```

This works because `parent public key` is really just `(parent private key)*G`, and `child public key` is just `(child private key)*G`.  That is, if we take the `CKDpriv` tweak equation and multiply all elements by `G`, we get exactly the `CKDpub` tweak equation.
`CKDpub` can only derive child `xpub` keys in the non-hardened index range.  This is because the information present in the parent `xpub`, specifically the public key in the `[ key ]`, only applies to the non-hardened range.
Where in `CKDpriv` we could use the private key to know the public key, we can't go the other way.  the `HMAC-SHA512` round that uses public keys in `CKDpriv` applies to the non-hardened index range.

Now that we have neutered `d` to create the xpub `D`, next in the path is `e`'s with index 1000000000 (or `3B9ACA00`), which is in the non-hardened range, so we should be able to derive `E` the child `xpub` from `D` using `CKDpub`.  We start with hmac-sha512 of the parent `chain code` as `hkey` and parent `key` (public key) concatenated with the child `E`'s index :

```
HMAC-SHA512( CFB71883F01676F587D023CC53A35BC7F88F724B1F8C2892AC1275AC822A3EDD,
             02E8445082A72F29B75CA48748A914DF60622A609CACFCE8ED0E35804560741D293B9ACA00 )

                            tweak                                                            chain code
37D3E49D8ECB854CC518BBA096F46795A9707860BF0FC95E5B19278C997098D4|C783E67B921D2BEB8F6B389CC646D7263B4145701DADD2161548A8B078E65E9E
```

Multiply the tweak by the generator `G` so we can tweak the parent's public key using point addition :

```
37D3E49D8ECB854CC518BBA096F46795A9707860BF0FC95E5B19278C997098D4 * G
= 0327E992F68217BC3E88CFFC3FEAB475880145413CBE008DB22B496DF4E1C3F864  <- tweak*G
```

Add the tweak to the parent point.  The result is the child's public key :

```
  0327E992F68217BC3E88CFFC3FEAB475880145413CBE008DB22B496DF4E1C3F864
+
  02E8445082A72F29B75CA48748A914DF60622A609CACFCE8ED0E35804560741D29
=
  022A471424DA5E657499D1FF51CB43C47481A03B1E77F951FE64CEC9F5A48F7011
```

Get the paren'ts fingerprint :

```
hash160(02E8445082A72F29B75CA48748A914DF60622A609CACFCE8ED0E35804560741D29) = D880D7D8....
```

Finally we can encode `E` :

```
0488B21E
05
D880D7D8
3B9ACA00
C783E67B921D2BEB8F6B389CC646D7263B4145701DADD2161548A8B078E65E9E
022A471424DA5E657499D1FF51CB43C47481A03B1E77F951FE64CEC9F5A48F7011
```

Neutering `d` to make `D` then deriving `E`, we can say that our path now looks like :

```
m / 0h / 1 / 2h / 2 / 1000000000
m / a  / b / c  / D / E
```

Or we can use the `N()` notation (for Neuter) to show where `CKDpub` was used, but I think it's less pretty.
`m / a  / b / c  / N(d / e)`

So to recap on your question, there are 3 different derivation methods, two using private keys and one using public keys :

1. `CKDpriv` to derive a child `xprv` at a hardened index
2. `CKDpriv` to derive a child `xprv` at a non-hardend index
3. `CKDpub` to derive a child `xpub` at a non-hardened index

Comment: I thought the extended key was just the (key + chain code)?

Comment: I think I burnt 5Kcal following through this answer. Joking aside, I honestly hope you are planning on writing an O'Reilly book on crypto wallets.

Comment: **secp256k** public key calculation is likely off: 1% % echo CBCE0D719ECF7431D88E6A89FA1483E02E35092AF60C042B1DF2FF59FA424DCA | bx ec-to-public
`0357bfe1e341d01c69fe5654309956cbea516822fba8a601743a012a7896ee8dc2` or 2% bx ec-multiply 0279BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798 CBCE0D719ECF7431D88E6A89FA1483E02E35092AF60C042B1DF2FF59FA424DCA
`0357bfe1e341d01c69fe5654309956cbea516822fba8a601743a012a7896ee8dc2`

Comment: is there a bx command to sum between (tweak * g) and the public key? ec-add doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I am also having a hard time trying to understand the stuff there. This is what I understand:

A simple insight is that for extended private key derivation and extended public key derivation, **they all have the same input (a parent public key and a parent chain node). As a result, they will have the same left 256 bits and right 256 bits.**

The difference is that,

for extended private key derivation, **the left 256 bits is added to the parent private key** to produce the child private key.

And for extended public key derivation, **the left 256 bits is added to the parent public key** to produce the child public key.

Both extended key derivation **use their right 256 bits output as the chain node, so the chain node is the same** for both derivations.

For hardened key derivation, the input is different from above extended key derivation.

Instead of using parent public key, **it uses parent private key with chain node as input** which will produce different 512 bits output. So the right 256 bits output which is used as chain node is different from the above mechanism.

Since the chain node is different, hackers can not deduce the private key using the chain node from extended derivation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Hardened keys are essentially generating new keys completely.

The whole benefit of using hierarchical keys is you can generate many public keys without access to the private keys. Later on, you can use the same method you used to generate on the public keys on the private keys and be able to spend the funds.

This is useful for example if you want a website to receive funds but not lose them if it gets hacked. The website can generate a new public key for each customer without ever touching private keys, thus keeping the funds more secure.

Hardened keys break this link. A hardened key operation can modify a private key to make a new one but NOT modify a public key.

They're not really critical as you could just generate a new key and have the same result but it's more convenient. You can more or less ignore hardened keys and just go on enjoying life =).

Comment: I disagree with that. Non-hardened derivation is vulnerable to situations where a private key may be shared and the extended pubkey may be known. Hardened derivation should be the default unless there is a good reason why you need to be able to generate public keys without access to the private key.